# Error ORA-12560 using Toad

Tags: oracle, toad, ora-12560

I am using toad with Oracle now, and after the installation, I tried to connect using toad, but an error pops up:

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

I have already tried to set the `ORACLE_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables but the issue is still here.

Could anybody help me with this?

p.s. I tried to start the listener but the NCA won't proceed to completion on my computer.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?